# NestJS Monorepo Microservice EJS Error Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "..\fin\dist\.."

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, microservices

I'm building a NestJS microservice app in monorepo with `fin` as the default microservice.

I'm using EJS templating.

But once I run the project, I get the error, "ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "D:\Studio\Work...\fin\dist\apps\views"".

I've tried different configurations for directory path in `app.setBaseViewsDir()` but all have not worked;

Could you please help me spot the problem?

Thanks in advance!

The project directory folder looks something like below;

```
+ fin
  + apps 
    + fin
      + src
        + views 

          -index.ejs

        -app.controller.ts

        -main.ts
  + image      

  -package.json

  -tsconfig.json
```

The fin `main.ts` file looks something like;

main.ts:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  app.useStaticAssets(resolve('../src/assets'));
  app.setBaseViewsDir(resolve('../src/views'));
  app.setViewEngine('ejs');
  await app.listen(6006);
  console.log(`Fin PEN started successfully on Port 6006`);
}
bootstrap();
```

The tsconfig.json looks like below.

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./"
    ...
  }
}
```